# Make a hyperlink textview in WhatsApp

Tags: android, url, hyperlink, textview

I tried this 
http://www.amazingtips247.co.uk/2015/09/the-super-lucky-saudi-man.html"> Whatsapp this

Answer (score 1):

Im not  cleat on your goal.
But whatsapp if you put an address it will show as hyperlink

http://www.amazingtips247.co.uk/2015/09/the-super-lucky-saudi-man.html

without the ">  at the end, it will show on whatsapp as hyperlink, as far as showing as a normal text it wont be an option on the current versions. You will need to add a space between the . and the url

Example 
testing.com--> result a hyperlink on whatsapp
testing. com--> result as text

Not 100% your goal, but hope this works for you.